# A function returns another function in php

Tags: php, class, oop

I dont know whether the question (the way I asked) is correct or not. I'm open for your suggestion. I want to know how exactly the following code works. If you want any details I can provide as much I want.

```
public function processAPI() {
    if (method_exists($this, $this->endpoint)) {
        return $this->_response($this->{$this->endpoint}($this->args));
    }
    return $this->_response("No Endpoint: $this->endpoint", 404);
}

private function _response($data, $status = 200) {
    header("HTTP/1.1 " . $status . " " . $this->_requestStatus($status));
    return json_encode($data);
}
private function _requestStatus($code) {
    $status = array(  
        200 => 'OK',
        404 => 'Not Found',   
        405 => 'Method Not Allowed',
        500 => 'Internal Server Error',
    ); 
    return ($status[$code])?$status[$code]:$status[500]; 
}
/**
 * Example of an Endpoint
 */
 protected function myMethod() {
    if ($this->method == 'GET') {
        return "Your name is " . $this->User->name;
    } else {
        return "Only accepts GET requests";
    }
 }
```

Here `$this->endpoint is 'myMethod' (a method I want to execute)`

I pass the method which I want to execute in the url. The function catches the request process then call the exact method. I want to how it's works. Especially this line.

```
return $this->_response($this->{$this->endpoint}($this->args));
```

Comment: You pass the method how? I can only see the internals of the class, not how you use it. What class is this? A framework? The line `$this->{$this->endpoint}($this->args)` is the same as `$this->theValueOfTheEndpointVariable($this->args)`, in your case: `$this->myMethod($this->arg)`.

Comment: PHP supports [variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php). The curly bracers around your endpoint tell PHP to resolve the value before using it as a variable see [PHP variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: @magnus I pass method by url. Not a framework I found this some tutorial in the internet.

Comment: @chappell Could be please elaborate in details. That part I want to know more.Please.

Comment: Sure, but where do you pass the method? I don't see any public methods accepting any arguments. How do you actually _use_ this class in a real life scenario? And if you found this in a tutorial, shouldn't that tutorial tell you what it does?!

Comment: There is a function to get the method name from url and assigns it to `$this-endpoint`. That's very clear and easy function.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson My guess is endpoint,args are constructor injected, so these are a part of a class where one instance is responsibe of handling one request eq. `$X = new X('dosgfunny',['with','this','args']);$X->processAPI();`

Comment: yes @cske that's correct. But how the `processApi()` methods works??

Comment: Well, if you read my first comment and the link that @R.Chappell gave you, you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: So we can call another function from return itself??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP Supports both [variable functions](http://php.net/manual/en/functions.variable-functions.php) and [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php).

When it reaches you statement within processApi

```
return $this->_response($this->{$this->endpoint}($this->args));
```

PHP will resolve your endpoint variable, we'll replace it with `myMethod` which is in your example:

```
return $this->_response($this->myMethod($this->args));
```

As you can see, we're now calling a method which exists on your class. If you set the endpoint to something which didn't exist, it would throw an error.

If myMethod returns a string such as `my name is bob` then once `$this->myMethod($this->args)` executes PHP will resolve that value as the argument for `$this->_response()` resulting in:

```
return $this->_response('my name is bob');
```

Following that chain of events, the `processAPI()` method will finally return that string JSON encoded as that's what the `_response` method does.

Comment: Hard to explain it better than that. :)

Comment: That's better. Thanks @magnus and @chappell!